# Converting a scripted ScriptModule to a Trace one

Tags: pytorch, torch, pytorch-lightning, torchscript

Is it possible to convert a script module to trace with dummy input tensors.
For building the model and saving the scriptmodule.

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch import optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import numpy as np

class TheModelClass(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TheModelClass, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

# Initialize model
model = TheModelClass()

# Initialize optimizer
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

# Print model's state_dict
print("Model's state_dict:")
for param_tensor in model.state_dict():
    print(param_tensor, "\t", model.state_dict()[param_tensor].size())

# Print optimizer's state_dict
print("Optimizer's state_dict:")
for var_name in optimizer.state_dict():
    print(var_name, "\t", optimizer.state_dict()[var_name])
    
m = torch.jit.script(model)
torch.jit.save(m, "model.pt")
```

Then for inference, I tried this code where I want the trace of the script module.

```
 import torch
 model=torch.jit.load('model.pt')
 dummy=torch.rand((1,3,224,224))
 traced=torch.jit.trace(model,dummy)
```

Following warning was thrown:

```
UserWarning: The input to trace is already a ScriptModule, tracing it is a no-op. Returning the object as is.
```

Comment: looks like it already is a trace. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: @Gulzar The warning says that it's a ScriptModule which I am trying to be traced. Is there a way to use ScriptModule like a traced one?

Comment: Have you tried just using it like a traced one?

Comment: Yes I did, but it's working like the script one, it has data dependent nodes like prim::if

Comment: Please show the code that doesn't work. Sounds line an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Gulzar The question already provide the code which produces this issue.
You may try this with any model in general.
You may try with any .pt file saved using torch.jit.save

Comment: Show code attempting to use as a traced not succeeding

Comment: @Gulzar I have added the entire code for developing the model, saving its scriptmodule and then loading it to find its trace.